# Odd time store behaviour in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, time

I have the following entry in my database:

```
t.time :my_time_stamp
```

In my controller I update it like this:

```
model.update_attributes(:my_time_stamp => Time.now.utc)
```

I can see that I'm writing:

```
Mon 9 November, 8:54.54 UTC 2009
```

However, when I later read this value I get:

```
Sat Jan 01 08:54:54 UTC 2000
```

It seems that the time part has been stored but not the date part.  I'd expect that because it's a time field, but why do I end up storing and retrieving a date? I guess I must be misunderstanding how this works in some fundamental way.... what am I doing wrong?

What I need to do is calculate the time in seconds since the update to the database.... is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby does not have a dateless time object, so it converts the dateless time field in your database to that time on some arbitrary day. Ruby's Time objects encode a number of seconds since the unix epoch, so they include the date. The correct way to store them in the database is with a datetime field, or if you prefer, you could use an integer field and store `Time.now.to_i`.

Answer (score 5):

A "time" field is storing only the time. Not the date.
So it's logic for you to get only a valid time and not a valid date.

If you wish to store date and time in the database, you should have the following migration :

```
t.datetime :my_time_stamp
```

Comment: I thought that, but I'm confused.  Doesn't time.now return a 'time' which is stored in the 'time :my_time_stamp' field, and when I later query it with model.my_time_stamp shouldn't I also get a time....?

Comment: Yeah but in the database you store only the time. So you don't get the date back.

Comment: yes, that's my point... if I do model.my_time_stamp then why is the 'type' of the returned value a date....?  Is it possibly because the database is really storing a datetime object?  If in the rails console I do :
model.update_attribute(:my_time_stamp, Time.now.utc), then I print model.my_time_stamp it looks like a date.....

Comment: Yeah because the Time object can store the date. But you should have a Time object, not a Date one. You can check that with doing something like `<%= model.my_time_stamp.class.to_s %>`  which should show you that you have a Time object and not a DateTime one.